# Start with Second Tablet on Google Play

Tags: google-play-store, multiple-devices

My old tablet was a LePan II from QVC.  It quit on me.  It wasn"t worth the money to have a pro look at/repair it. So, I got a Proscan PLT9045K (from ShopNBC).  After I got it charged, I went straight to Google Play, but I do not see how to add a new device.  I understand that there's not really a way to delete the original device from my account (and if there is I'd like some help there).  How can I connect my new tablet with my existing Google Play account.  I really don't want to set up a new gmail.

Comment: What do you mean that you "went straight to Google Play"?  As in [Play Store website](https://play.google.com/store)?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry,I'm not up on specific terminology.  I did mean the Store.

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is to enter the account information on the new tablet.  It should ask you for it (along with the other stuff like the time and date) when you first power the device up.  Alternatively, it will ask you for it when you open up the play store/market app on the device.

There's no need to remove the previous device from your account nor is there any way to.  You can have at least 10 devices associated to the same google account at the same time.

Also, the device will automatically get removed from your account after it hasn't been in contact with the play store for about 9 months.

Comment: My new tablet already knew the date & time.  It didn"t ask me for anything.    I'd like to find where it should have.  When I went to Google, I just logged in with my email address and password.  Should it have recognized I was on a new device?

Comment: My old tablet already had the Play Store on it.  Do I need to get it on the new tablet?  If yes, how?

Comment: Don't you have it on the new tablet?

Answer (score 1):

This device isn't listed in [Google's list of devices supported by Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en-GB#P). Not all Android devices have (or can run) Google Play: Android is open-source, so anyone can make an Android device, but only those certified by the Open Handset Alliance are allowed the Google apps and Google Play. It doesn't seem likely you'll be able to use Google Play with this device.

The manufacturer's website looks like it was made by children, and ShopNBC is the only retailer that advertises the device. I'd suggest you stop buying tablets that are cheaply made for shopping channels and buy one from a reputable manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks anyway.  I guess I'll have to find new apps through Amazon Appstore and Apptoide.